# Django - Optional field with Serializer

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework, model

I want to automatically generate the "path" field of my model when I use the create method of my serializer. Otherwise I would like to be able to pass this field in my request to be able to modify it later.
I haven't found a way to make a single field of my template optional.
Here is my model :

**models.py**

```
class Shop(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    category = models.ForeignKey(ShopCategory, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    path = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    mustBeLogged = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    deliveries = models.FloatField(default=7)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Here is my code :

**serializer.py**

```
class ShopSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Shop
        exclude = ['path']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        path = validated_data["name"].replace(" ", "-").lower()
        path = unidecode.unidecode(path)
        unique = False
        while unique == False:
            if len(Shop.objects.filter(path=path)) == 0:
                unique = True
            else:
                # Generate a random string
                char = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
                path += "-{}".format("".join(random.sample(char, 5)))
        shop = Shop.objects.create(**validated_data, path=path)
        shop.save()
        return shop
```

**views.py**

```
def post(self, request):
        """For admin to create shop"""
        serializer = ShopSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors)
```

Comment: I didn't understand this part: if len(Shop.objects.filter(path=path)) == 0:

Comment: @Neeraj I check if there is already the same path and depending on it I add a character string behind (because a link must be unique)

Comment: are you not able to save path? You are doing it correctly in serailizer whats the issue with your code?

Comment: @Neeraj Yes my code works with the create method but I would like to set up a PUT method reusing the same serializer to change the path

Comment: @Neeraj The create method is the only one for which I don't need to pass my path in my arguments

Answer (score 1):

You can set path to be accepted as Null and pop it in create method. In this way you won't have to add it in `exclude`.

```
class ShopSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    path = serializers.CharField(allow_blank=True, allow_null=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Shop
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        validated_data.pop('path')
        path = validated_data["name"].replace(" ", "-").lower()
        path = unidecode.unidecode(path)
        unique = False
        while unique == False:
            if len(Shop.objects.filter(path=path)) == 0:
                unique = True
            else:
                # Generate a random string
                char = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
                path += "-{}".format("".join(random.sample(char, 5)))
        shop = Shop.objects.create(**validated_data, path=path)
        shop.save()
        return shop
    
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        #You will have path in validated_data
        #And you may have to check if the values are null
        return super(ShopSerializer, self).update(instance, validated_data)
```

Apart from this, in your code:

```
while unique == False:
                if len(Shop.objects.filter(path=path)) == 0:
```

This would be very costly operation. In every loop it would fire a query, I'm not sure about the logic behind it but you may want to change this.

Comment: I get this error : ```AssertionError at /v1/shops
("Creating a ModelSerializer without either the 'fields' attribute or the 'exclude' attribute has been deprecated since 3.3.0, and is now disallowed. Add an explicit fields = '__all__' to the ShopSerializer serializer.",)```

Comment: oops please add fields = `'__all__'` in your serailizer

Comment: When I add the fields = '__all__', I get the same error telling me that the field 'path' is required. I think the changes do not apply to the model directly

Comment: You are changing it in serializer , model has nothing to do with it

Comment: I think its because your path is unique field

Comment: I tried removing unique = True from my path field but I still get the same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231226/discussion-between-neeraj-and-bastien).